# Amstockchart - multiple comparision not working when "DataSetSelector" is "top"

Tags: javascript, php, charts, stock

I am using amstockcharts. It is working well but when I put dataSetSelector's position to top it doesnt allow to compare multiple charts. Please let me know if there is anything I am going wrong

```
// DATA SET SELECTOR
var dataSetSelector = new AmCharts.DataSetSelector();
dataSetSelector.position = "top";
dataSetSelector.selectText = "select";
dataSetSelector.compareText = "compare to";
chart.dataSetSelector = dataSetSelector;
```